# Use javascript run select option in MySQL query

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have a select box which is linked through JS. I'm trying to make it so that the option chosen is essentially saved, so that when 'refresh attendees' is clicked, only the attendees from the selected group get refreshed.

**select box**

```
<select name="users" onChange="showYes(this.value); showNo(this.value); showUn(this.value);" style="font-size: 14px; font-family: open-sans,sans-serif; font-weight: 700; line-height: 17px;" id="attactivity">
          <option value="">Select Activity</option>
          <option value="CMA">CMA</option>
          <option value="CM2">CM2</option>
          <option value="CMB">CMB</option>
          <option value="CPM">CMP</option>
```

**MySQL**

```
    $refreshatt = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['refreshatt']);
    $attactivity= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['attactivity']);
    // See if that product name is an identical match to another product in the system

    $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE stats SET attend='0' WHERE activity='attactivity'");
    header("location: admin-page.php"); 
    exit();
}
?>
```

Right now, it is not getting anything as attactivity, so no group is being refreshed. Any suggestions?

As a heads-up: I have tried the query stating a group (i.e. CMA, CM2, etc) and the everything works. It seems to be just getting the value of 'attactivity'

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are posting your form data correctly, your issue is your query. You have insert a literal `attactivity` instead of the variable.

```
$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE stats SET attend='0' WHERE activity='attactivity'");
```

vs.

```
$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE stats SET attend='0' WHERE activity='$attactivity'");
```

#### Additional Recommendations:

- Read about [Strings in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)
- Do not use the `mysql` extension. Please use [something else](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php).
- Read about [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: Hey Jason, my bad. I had already tried it with that to no avail.. tried it again with nothing happening.

Comment: Check your data is posted correctly by debugging your variable values.

Comment: Hey Jason, just had a check and attactivity is coming back as NULL... any idea why?

Comment: What's in `$_POST['attactivity']`?

Comment: Also comes up with NULL